Ant Design Chart x and y scale starting position
When I encounter the same y values ​​or a small amount of x values
How to make the starting position of the y-axis scale align with the bottom, and the starting position of the X-axis scale align with the left
enter image description here
enter image description here
// my config
const config = {
       
        data,
        // height: 400,
        // width: 400,
        xField: "item",
        yField: "value",
        point: {
            shapeField: "circle",
            sizeField: 6,
        },
      
        style: {
            lineWidth: 2, 
            // stroke: "#f3f3f3", 
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                labelSpacing: 16, 
                ...axisXYShared,
                labelFormatter: (dataum: string) => dataum + "day",
            },
            y: {
                labelSpacing: 32, 
                ...axisXYShared,
                labelDirection: "negative",
            },
        },

        tooltip: false,
        
    };

I have referenced the file scale configuration and tested it, but it does not work.

You can set the range of the axes values. Check the documentation: https://ant-design-charts.antgroup.com/en/options/plots/scale/linear

I don't quite understand the specific function of the "range" attribute file. Does it need to be dynamically set? There is no attribute that can define alignment.
